# Error: constructor IllegalSquareSideException in class IllegalSquareSideException cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Square extends IllegalSquareSideException
{
    private double side;

    public Square(double side) throws IllegalSquareSideException
    {
        if (side < 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalSquareSideException("Illegal Square Side!");
        }
            this.side = side;
    }

    public void setSide(double side)
    {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public double getSide()
    {
        return side;
    }
}
```

This is my user-defined IllegalSquareSideException

```
public class IllegalSquareSideException extends Exception
{
    public IllegalSquareSideException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the problem? Did you try recompiling?

Comment: @D.Lawrence yeah, I tried recompiling but the error is still the same.

Comment: it seems unlikely... Are you sure there is no other place in your code than instantiate an ```IllegalSquareSideException```?

Comment: I only instantiated my user-defined exception in the Square class. In my main class, I only instantiated the Square class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Square` extends `IllegalSquareSideException`. `IllegalSquareSideException` has a constructor with a String value.

Therefore, your `Square` class expects that you call a super constructor of `IllegalSquareSideException`. As you might know, the compiler tries to insert the call to the no-args constructor if no super call is specified. Sadly, the no-args constructor doesn't exist in `IllegalSquareSideException`, hence the error.

In your case, it doesn't make much sense to `extends IllegalSquareSideException`. I would therefore recommend that you remove that extension:

```java
public class Square {
    private double side;

    public Square(double side) throws IllegalSquareSideException {
        if (side < 0) {
            throw new IllegalSquareSideException("Illegal Square Side!");
        }
        this.side = side;
    }

    public void setSide(double side) {
        this.side = side;
    }

    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
}
```

Finally, you could ask yourself why you extended the `Square` class with `IllegalSquareSideException`. Is `Square` a child class of an exception? Does that make any sense?